# Looking for reference giving exposition on Pell's Equation

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, pell-type-equations

I know the continued fraction convergence method of finding a solution of Pell's equation . I am looking for other methods of finding the smallest or at least one solution of Pell's equation which is connected to abstract algebra (group and ring theory ) or by some classical approach . Please give some reference ,  links which  gives a thorough , detailed exposition . Thanks in advance

Comment: [The serious part of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#References).

Comment: http://djm.cc/library/Algebra_Elementary_Text-Book_Part_II_Chrystal_edited02.pdf